# RB How can I use Lookup expression on DB for report visibility

Tags: reporting-services

This is 2008R2. I have a dataset with a query "DESIGN" on a database with results for a export format like this:

```
| pdf   | true  |
| rdl   | false |
| excel | true  |
```

My Goal is to change the visibility depending on the export format of the report. The property of the visibility can be changed in the Database, so I need it to be dynamic. If I export to pdf, a specific textbox or tablix should hidden... I tried Lookup on a separate textbox which gives me the RenderFormat. And used the expression in the Hidden-property.

```
=Lookup(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value
  , Fields!RenderFormat.Value
  , Fields!Hidden.Value
  , "DESIGN")
```

I also tried it with 1 and 0 values in the database and converted it to CBool(...) but it appears to be a bug or something like that, because the value of the Textbox1 just disappears when the report is rendered. So there is no possibility for the Lookup to work.
With `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` instead of `ReportItems!Textbox1.Value` it is not working either...
It would be great if you could help me!

There can also be an easier way... if you know it... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!!! A solution to the problem is the following:

1) First I have to create some VB-Code: Rightklick beside the ReportBody to open the ReportProperties. Than the following Code should be used to create a valuetype string variable:

```
Public Shared Dim rf as String 
Public Function Setrf (ByVal var as String)
 rf = var
End Function
```

2) A TextBox should be added to fill the variable. The TextBox expression should be:

```
=Code.Setrf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name)
```

3) The Tablix Propertie Hidden should get the following Lookup expression refering to the Code:

```
   =Lookup(Code.rf, 
           Fields!Reporttyp.Value, 
           CBool(Fields!LegendeVersteckt.Value), "Design")
```

This is for the case of true and false being 1 and 0. Now on differen export Format it is Hidden or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping this would be as simple as using a report parameter which could then be fed into the WHERE clause of your query. However, parameters aren't allowed to use the Globals!RenderFormat.Name field (I don't know why). I'm not sure about how to use a lookup expression to pull back this as you asked for, but I used the following nested IIF function to toggle visibility in the Hidden expression of a textbox based on rendered format:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name=nothing,true,
    IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCEL",false,
        IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",false,true)))
```

As you were going to have a single query that holds the boolean visibility values anyway, this option may not be bad. The only problem will be maintaining it in the many different locations you probably need it. I would recommend storing it in a hidden textbox and then copying and pasting from that as needed so you have one place where you change the function and you don't have to worry about typos but once.

In my testing, I found that the Render Formats are case-sensitive, and that for the report viewer rendering, the format name is RPL, not rdl.

The most comprehensive list I could find of Rendering Formats in correct case is below and came from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx

HTML3.2
HTML4.0
HTMLOWC
MHTML
IMAGE
EXCEL
CSV
PDF
XML

I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I had this idea as well, but the problem is that there will be hundrets of reports and to change them all would be heavy stuff. Thats why I wanted to use "Lookup" in the database. And of course you're right its RPL :)